# Trouble with encoding special chars for URL through text input

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm building a PHP application using CodeIgniter. It is similar to `Let Me Google That For You` where you write a sentence into a text input box, click submit, and you are taken to a URL that displays the result. I wanted the URL to be human-editable, and relatively simple. I've gotten around the CodeIgniter URL routing, so right now my URLs can look something like this:

```
http://website.com/?q=this+is+a+normal+url
```

The problem right now is when the sentence contains a special character like a question mark, or a backslash. Both of these mess with my current `.htaccess` rewrite rules, and it happens even when the character is encoded.

```
http://website.com/?q=this+is+a+normal+url? OR
http://website.com/?q=this+is+a+normal+url%3F
```

What does work is double-encoding. For example, if I take the question mark, and encode it to `%253F` (where the ? is encoded to %3F and the % sign is encoded to %25). This url works properly.

```
http://website.com/?q=this+is+a+normal+url%253F
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do here? Is there a clever way I could double encode the input? Can I write a `.htaccess` rewrite rule to get around this? I'm at a loss here. Here are the rewrite rules I'm currently using for everyone.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/app/create/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
```

**Note**: The way CodeIgniter works is they have a `index/application/function/parameter` URL setup. I'm feeding the function the full query string right now.

Comment: Can you add your rewrite rule to the question?

Comment: Sure thing, the original post has been edited to include the rewrite rules.

Comment: Is it necessary to redirect the request in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your’re using Apache 2.2 and later, you can use the [B flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to force the backreference to be escaped:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.*
RewriteRule ^ /index.php/app/create/%0? [L,B]
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the .htaccess file to use what you had and it worked exactly as I needed. I would vote you reputation points if I had any to give.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do human readable urls like this

```
$humanReadableUrl= implode("_",preg_split('/\W+/', trim($input), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

It will remove any non-word characters and will add underscores beetween words

Comment: Unfortunately things like punctuation are necessary for the app (the users are going to want to put in exclamations, periods, and question marks).